# AngularJS-Toaster number of toasts in toaster-container

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used [Angular-toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) and it seems awesome. Searching stack and not found that: 
How can I store number of open toasts in toaster-container in my controller?

```
angular.module('main', ['toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('myController', function($scope, toaster) {
    $scope.pop = function(){
        toaster.pop('info', "title", "text");
    };
    $scope.toastCount = function(){
         //solution goes here
    }
});
```

in html:

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
```

The code above is somehow pseudo, so you should be familiar with Angular-toaster to answer this question.
Many thanks for any help ;)

Comment: You want all opened toasts count or current open toasts count. Also why do you want to get count of your open toasts.

Comment: I want currently opened toasts. I need it somewhere in program. if there are no open toasts, I want to hide a button.

Comment: Hi Ali , i have posted my answer does this work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angularjs-toaster's `onShowCallback` and `onHideCallback` to get currently open toaster count like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, toaster, $window) {
  $scope.count = 0
  $scope.pop = function() {
    toaster.pop({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Success',
      body: 'This will work !',
      onHideCallback: function() {
        $scope.count--;
      },
      onShowCallback: function() {
        $scope.count++;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

As you can see on `onShowCallback` i have incremented count and on `onHideCallback` i have decremented the count to get currently open toaster count.

Also here is a working example: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/5WPdpYZJXUX5316obPej?p=preview